# Laravel save data as JSON in database without escaping URL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In the `store` function I would like to save JSON data in a database without escaping the URL, for example:

```
$arr = [
    'images'=>['original'=>'/uploads/contents/' . basename($filename)],
    'thumbnail'=>'/uploads/contents/' . basename($filename)
];

$data = Contents::create([
    'title' => $request->title,
    'description' => $request->description,
    'featured_images' => $arr,
    'visit' => 0,
]);
```

To store this result as `$arr` in the database I have:

```
{
    "images":
          {"original":"\/uploads\/contents\/636459965493789558.jpg"},
    "thumbnail":"\/uploads\/contents\/636459965493789558.jpg"
}
```

In that, URLs escaped. How can I store that without escaping URLs?

My model option:

```
protected $casts=[
    'featured_images'=>'array'
];
```

Comment: Do you need them unescaped because you intend to do string matches on the database directly? I see no other reason why that would be necessary

Comment: The escapes are entirely harmless in this context. Why do you want to get rid of them?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't like the slashes? [RTM](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators): *adding the array cast to that attribute will automatically deserialize the attribute to a PHP array when you access it on your Eloquent model* - You could json_encode before with JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES and just cast store as string, but then you lose the automatic deserialization.

Answer (score 2):

You can encode your json manually to prevent slashes this way

```
json_encode($value, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: using this tips store this data on database `"{\"images\":{\"original\":\"\/uploads\/contents\/636453857006939814.jpg\"},\"thumbnail\":\"\/uploads\/contents\/636453857006939814.jpg\"}"`

Comment: Honestly, I don't recommend you to disable this feature. Problems may arise once you decode the json string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should leave it like that.
Whenever you want to use it, just `json_decode` like this.

```
<?php
$a = json_decode('{
    "images":
          {"original":"\/uploads\/contents\/636459965493789558.jpg"},
    "thumbnail":"\/uploads\/contents\/636459965493789558.jpg"
}', true);
echo $a["images"]["original"];
?>
```

Result:

```
/uploads/contents/636459965493789558.jpg
```

Comment: There would be no json to decode, the op would access it like `$data->featured_images['images']['original']`, as its larval model with casting mutator, but I think this is a question to ask a question with no real reason to ask but to ask.